# Please suggest a good book for non-linear DEs.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, nonlinear-analysis

Is there any good/famous book about non linear differential equations ? ..
With practice problems and solutions.

Thank you

Comment: Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations: An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers by Dominic Jordan ,‎ Peter Smith **and** Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations: Problems and Solutions: A Sourcebook for Scientists and Engineers

Comment: Make sure to look at both books...